# Set current DateTime seconds and millis to 0 in C#

Tags: c#, date, datetime

Currently I'm using this:

```
new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day,
             DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, 0)
```

Is there any other way to directly set seconds and milliseconds to 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your current code is dangerous, as you're evaluating `DateTime.Now` multiple times. The current time can change between two calls, so you could end up with inconsistent values. It would be better as:

```cs
// Do you *definitely* want the current date/time in the system  local time zone?
// Might be correct for local client apps; almost certainly not for server-side code.
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime rounded = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute, 0);
```

That's not too bad. Another alternative would be:

```cs
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime rounded = now.Date + new TimeSpan(now.Hour, now.Minute, 0);
```

If you definitely want to use `DateTime`, and you definitely want to use the system local time zone, that's probably what I'd do.

As a plug for my [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org) project, that would be something like:

```cs
rounded = now.With(TimeAdjusters.TruncateToMinute);
```

... but you'd have a lot more options to consider in terms of what type you wanted `now` to be in the first place.